# Specialize a value with C# generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I have some C++ code that implements a basic `Pixel` class. Here's just a stub of the important bits I have:

```
// Pixel.h
template <class SizeType>
struct Pixel
{
public:
    typedef SizeType Size;
    Size R;
    Size G;
    Size B;
    static Size Min;
    static Size Max;

    TPixel(Size R = Min, Size G = Min, Size B = Min);
};

#include "Pixel.impl"


// Pixel.impl
template <class SizeType> SizeType Pixel<SizeType>::Min = std::numeric_limits<Size>::min();
template <class SizeType> SizeType Pixel<SizeType>::Max = std::numeric_limits<Size>::max();
template <> float Pixel<float>::Min = 0;
template <> float Pixel<float>::Max = 1;
template <> double Pixel<double>::Min = 0;
template <> double Pixel<double>::Max = 1;
```

And in C# I'm trying to duplicate this:

```
struct Pixel<Size> where Size : struct
{
    public Size R;
    public Size G;
    public Size B;
    public static const Size Min; // What should I do here?
    public static const Size Max;
}
```

Except I have no idea how I can include this Min / Max size into the type. I'd like to be able to have a uniform Pixel interface which allows you do things like clamping, adding, scaling, etc.

I'm running into a similar solution when I'm trying to deal with Vectors and Matrices of potentially arbitrary type. Can anyone advise me on how I can accomplish what the above C++ code is doing?

Comment: If I am reading that right you want to know how to do template specialization in C#?

Comment: Generics do not work across values, only types.

Comment: Generic parameter types should begin with an Uppercase T, if you wish to adhere to Microsoft naming conventions, i.e. `Pixel<TSize>`. Guidelines are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx

Comment: Still C# is not very well suited for hardcore computational geometry or numerical analysis, I hope they will do more about this in the future!

Comment: Do you really have a need for both `double` and `float` types?  I think OpenGL unified on `float`.  If you make a similar decision it will make your interfaces much simpler, and probably will have perf benefits.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: If I was working with OpenGL I would. I need the generic types for some image processing. Unrelated to this, I was also wondering if it were possible to write essentially a generic numerical matrix, but that seems impossible in C# at the moment.

Comment: @Mike: If you want a .Net language that's a bit more suited to numeric processing, you might want to look at F#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C++ template specialization, there is no such thing as specialization of a generic in .Net.

You can't initialize a `T` instance to anything but a `T`, unless you have a constraint, so you can't use a static constructor to try to work around the problem.

As far as I know, there is no constraint that allows you to specify only types that either are numeric types, or have conversions from numeric types.

I suggest you just make two different types of classes:

```
public struct PixelFloat
{
    public float R { get; set; }
    public float G { get; set; }
    public float B { get; set; }
    public const float Min = 0.0f;
    public const float Max = 1.0f;
}

public struct PixelDouble
{
    public double R { get; set; }
    public double G { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public const double Min = 0.0f;
    public const double Max = 1.0f;
}
```

This is effectively the same thing anyhow, as this is what it would compile to under the covers.  Other solutions won't buy you much compared to this, as you'll still have to type in the type: `Pixel<double>` `Pixel<float>`.

Also, in cases like this, I would suggest you use names that show that you're using types from your generic parameters. `Size` isn't obviously a generic parameter. `TSize` is. And `TSize` doesn't describe what the type does, it just describes how it varies. Instead you should name it something like `TValue`.

Comment: @Merlyin Morgan-Graham - Why not inlcude your comment in your answer? :/

Comment: @Polity: Alright.  It felt like it wasn't directly related but I'll move it into the answer anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this sort of thing would be to add an interface constraint to `Size` which requires `Size` to have `Max` and `Min` methods or something like that. Of course, the definitions would no longer be necessary in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you are trying to accomplish is to do template specialization in C# generics, this is not possible.

Here is an [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) comparing the differences between the two but the highlights are:

- C# does not support explicit specialization; that is, a custom implementation of a template for a specific type.
- C# does not support partial specialization: a custom implementation for a subset of the type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like this:

```
static class Pixel
{
    public static Size Min<Size>() where Size : struct;
    public static Size Max<Size>() where Size : struct;
}

struct Pixel<Size> where Size : struct
{
    public Size R;
    public Size G;
    public Size B;
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
Pixel<double> doublePixel;
var max = Pixel.Max<double>();
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
public struct Pixel<Size> where Size : struct
{
    private enum DEF_TYPES
    {
        MIN,
        MAX
    }

    private static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<DEF_TYPES, object>> m_Defs = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<DEF_TYPES, object>>
    {
        {
            typeof(float),
                new Dictionary<DEF_TYPES, object> {
                    {DEF_TYPES.MIN, 0f},
                    {DEF_TYPES.MAX, 1f}
                }
        },

        {
            typeof(double),
                new Dictionary<DEF_TYPES, object> {
                    {DEF_TYPES.MIN, 0d},
                    {DEF_TYPES.MAX, 1d}
                }
        }
    };

    private static Size GetValue(DEF_TYPES def_type)
    {
        if(!m_Defs.ContainsKey(typeof(Size)))
            throw new ArgumentException("No default values for template " + typeof(Size));
        if(!m_Defs[typeof(Size)].ContainsKey(def_type))
            throw new ArgumentException("No default value '" + def_type + "' for template " + typeof(Size));
        return (Size)m_Defs[typeof(Size)][def_type];
    }

    public Size R;
    public Size G;
    public Size B;
    public static readonly Size Min = GetValue(DEF_TYPES.MIN);
    public static readonly Size Max = GetValue(DEF_TYPES.MAX);
}
```

And used as:

```
Console.WriteLine(Pixel<float>.Max);
Console.WriteLine(Pixel<float>.Min);
Console.WriteLine(Pixel<double>.Max);
Console.WriteLine(Pixel<double>.Min);
```

And;

```
Pixel<double>.Min = 4;
```

Won't compile, as expected.

Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: That would work.  A little screwy, but solves the problem and is as close to the original interface as possible.